# Why did Anakin join Palpatine in the dark side if Palpatine did not have the power to cheat death?

Tags: star-wars, anakin-skywalker

In *Revenge of the Sith*, Palpatine states to Anakin (when Anakin became Palpatine's apprentice):

> To cheat death is a power only one has achieved but if we work together I know we can discover the secret.

So right there Anakin knows Palpatine doesn't know how to cheat death.  Padme is a few months pregnant when this happens. So Anakin really thinks he can join the dark side, become Palpatine's apprentice, AND learn how to cheat death all before Padme gives birth in a few months? As Palpatine said, *"cheating death is a power only one has achieved"* so this means it could take YEARS to learn-- but Padme is giving birth in only a few months-- so what was Anakin's plan here?

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/48866/76048

Comment: It's the better option from his point of view. Either he doesn't join Palpatine and therefore won't learn the secret and so Padme is certainly going to die. Or he joins Palpatine and hopes they can find the secret quite quickly. I.e. it's some hope versus no hope for him.

Comment: You seem to be implicitly assuming that Anakin knew that Padme was going to die, is that the case? Anakin's reaction on Padme's death would seem to indicate it was a shock and possibly a surprise or am I misreading the situation?

Comment: @Bitterdreggs. -- Maybe... Anakin had been having dreams that Padme would die (I wonder if Palpatine didn't have anything to do with that), so he was certainly predisposed to Palpatine's machinations. During the [Frankenstein scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dpZdpf30BqM), Vader asks Palpatine if Padme is safe & alive. He of course lies and says not that she is dead (which Anakin might have expected), but rather that **Vader killed her**. Vader says he couldn't have done it. Palpatine's evil grin speaks more than any words. Anakin is shocked at the accusation more than the fact.

Comment: Thanks ellie, I think it deserves a re-watch, it's been a while. @elemtilas